# How to get OnTriggerStay2D working?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I am trying to make a flamethrower weapon for my player character. I am using a system were I can change between weapons, and every other weapon works perfectly. The flamethrower is able to turn on its particle system, but the `OnTriggerStay2D` that I am using to detect if the flames are hitting an enemy is not working. From other answers to similar questions, I have seen that it is commonly due to there not being a `Collider` and/or `Rigidbody`, and I have both. (`CapsuleCollider2D`, with" is trigger" set to true, in the shape of the area the flames occupy)

Here is my code:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Flamer collision");
    if (isFlamer && canshoot && flamerOn && other.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        Debug.Log("flamer firing");
        if (timeBtwShots == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("flamer damage applying");
            health = other.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().health;
            Debug.Log(other.name + " health: " + health);
            health -= damage;

            timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
            Instantiate(ash, other.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }
}
```

I am not receiving any error messages or `Debug.Log`s in the console.

The rest of the code works, and is just to turn the particle system on and off, aim the flamethrower, and turn the flamethrower on and off.

[image: Inspector settings]

These are the `Rigidbody2D` and `Collider2D` settings.

here is a screenshot of the flamethrower when it is meant to damage an enemy:
[image]

Edit:

Some people have asked for more screenshots of the whole inspector:
[image]

- When the flamethrower is selected.

[image]

- When the enemy is selected (note: the large box collider is for the enemy to detect melee attack range, and the small capsule collider is for the enemy's body.)

Here is a screenshot of my Layers:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of my sorting layers:
[image]

All of my objects have the z-coordinate 0.

Comment: Is this script on the same object as the Rigidbody2D, or a child or parent object? What layer is that object on? What layer are the objects you want to hit with the flamethrower on? Do those objects have colliders and rigidbodies? How are your physics layers configured? Can you show us a screenshot of the scene view in play mode with the flamethrower selected, showing the bounds of its collider, overlapping an object it should be detecting?

Comment: it is on the same object as the rigidbody2D. the object is on a different layer to the enemies, but i have had not any issues with other weapons not detecting enemies. the enemies do have colliders and rigidbodies.

Comment: Not fully related to your error but don't compare against 0 ( this one `timeBtwShots == 0`). Since you substract `Time.deltaTime`, you might end with a value below zero and that code is never getting executed and you will just remove more time from it.

Comment: My first step to troubleshoot such a problem would be to put a debugger breakpoint in the beginning of this `OnTriggerStay2D` method to confirm that it even gets called. Then I would continue debugging step-by-step from there to check if any of these `if`-conditions don't trigger the way I believe they should.

Comment: I already have a debugger in the places you have described. the onTriggerStay2D simply never gets called

Comment: For us to help you solve this, we need screenshots of the full Inspector for the flames and for the enemy, as well as the layer collision matrix in your project settings.

Comment: What is a layer collision matrix? also, I have other weapons with the same layer settings but different collision detection functions and they work fine. and the flames themselves aren't doing anything with the physics, its just the capsule collider 2d

Comment: You can read about the Layer Collision Matrix here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html